# What is the correct way to change image channel ordering between channels first and channels last?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, theano

I can not for the life of me figure out how to switch the image ordering. images are read in (x,x,3) format, theano requires it to be in (3,x,x) format. I tried changing the order with
`numpy.array([img[:,:,i] for i in range(3)])`

which i guess gets the job done, but it is both ugly and i can't figure out how to reverse it to get the original image back.

Comment: Try `img.transpose(2,0,1)` or  `img.transpose(2,1,0)`.

Comment: If you use `torchvision`, you can also use `torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()(img)`. It will do that automatically for you.

Comment: But be aware that `torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()(img)` scales your images, and sometimes you don't want that.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I agree with @Qualia 's comment, [np.moveaxis(a, source, destination)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) is easier to understand. This does the job:

```
x = np.zeros((12, 12, 3))
x.shape
#yields: 
(12, 12, 3)

x = np.moveaxis(x, -1, 0)
x.shape
#yields: 
(3, 12, 12)
```

Answer (score 32):

#### To reorder data

You can use [numpy.rollaxis](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) to roll the axis 3 to position 1 (considering you have the batch size as dimension 0).

```
np.rollaxis(imagesArray, 3, 1)
```

But, if you're using keras, you might want to change its configuration or define it per layer. Theano doesn't require anything from you if you're using Keras.

Keras can be configured with channels first or channels last, besides allowing you to define it in every individual layer, so you don't have to change your data.

#### To configure keras

Find the `keras.json` file and change it. The file is usually installed in `C:\Users\yourusername\.keras` or `~/.keras` depending on your OS.

Change `"image_data_format": "channels_last"` to `"channels_first"` or vice-versa, as you wish.

Usually, working with "channels_last" is less troublesome because of a great amount of other (non convolutional) functions that work only on the last axis.

#### Defining channel order in layers.

The [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) has all information about parameters for layers, including the `data_format` parameter.

Comment: I find `np.moveaxis` more intuitive for this purpose.

Answer (score 20):

If you're looking at the fastest option, go for `.transpose(...)`. It's even faster than `np.einsum`.

```py
img = np.random.random((1000, 1000, 3))
img.shape
# (1000, 1000, 3)

%timeit img.transpose(2, 0, 1)
# 385 ns ± 1.11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit np.rollaxis(img, -1, 0)
# 2.7 µs ± 50.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit np.einsum('ijk->kij', img)
# 2.75 µs ± 31.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit np.moveaxis(img, -1, 0)
# 7.26 µs ± 57.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

np.allclose(img.transpose(2, 0, 1), np.einsum('ijk->kij', img))
# True
np.allclose(img.transpose(2, 0, 1), np.moveaxis(img, -1, 0))
# True
np.allclose(img.transpose(2, 0, 1), np.rollaxis(img,-1, 0))
# True
```

Answer (score 10):

Using `np.moveaxis` is effective, but I have found that `np.einsum` is much faster.

```
x = np.zeros((12,12,3))
%timeit np.moveaxis(x,-1,0)
#yields 7.46 µs ± 312 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.einsum('ijk->kij',x)
#yields 1.11 µs ± 31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = np.zeros((12, 12, 3))
y = np.rollaxis(x, 2, 0)
y.shape

(3, 12, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use torch.permute in PyTorch:

```
x = torch.randn(2, 3, 5)
x.size()
torch.Size([2, 3, 5])
torch.permute(x, (2, 0, 1)).size()
torch.Size([5, 2, 3])
```