# Traffic sign classification - OOM when allocating tensor of shape [] and type float

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am currently trying to improve algorithm from this [tutorial](https://chsasank.github.io/keras-tutorial.html). More specifically the layers of CNN model.

```
def cnn_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     input_shape=(3, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
                     activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    ########### The problem occurs when this is removed ############
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    ################################################################

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

To get better accuracy, I tried to add new layer, or remove one (before flattening), but if I do so, I am getting following error

> OOM when allocating tensor of shape [] and type float

I am new to machine learning and don't really understand the error. I know what the convolutional/dense/pooling layers do but I am not really sure how to practically use them in model.

So my questions are:

- Why am i getting such an error ?
- May somebody give some advices how to get better accuracy or point me to some good tutorial about creating CNN models ?

**EDIT:**

Iam running this on gpu, IMG_SIZE is 32 and batch size is 32. Its running fine unless i add or romove layer in model. Stack trace can be found [here](https://ideone.com/hnq62i). I know its memory allocation error, and it seems it has something to do with shapes of input.

Comment: what is your IMG_SIZE, batch size and do you use a gpu?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of code changes you did that lead to the error?

Comment: This is a memory allocation error. Can you please post the traceback as well.

Comment: Question is edited. @SashaTsukanov For example i remove the third convolution layer and this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error

> Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 2 for
>   'conv2d_8/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,256,2,2],
>   [3,3,256,256].

This is probably something to do with your channel position (channels last or first)

Try channels last, replace:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=(3, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
                 activation='relu'))
```

with:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3),
                 activation='relu'))
```

Comment: You are right, but i had to also set `data_format="channels_last"`, even if in the docs is `channels_last` is default.

Comment: @FilipKočica You can adjust your default channel position in `keras.json` file https://stackoverflow.com/a/43833679/7541374