# Pytorch tensor to change dimension

Tags: pytorch

I have a RGB image tensor as (3,H,W), but the plt.imshow() can not show RGB image with this  shape. I want to change the tensor to (H,W,3). How can I do that, is pytorch function .view() can do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to change image channel ordering between channels first and channels last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829711/what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-image-channel-ordering-between-channels-first)

Comment: @Deusy94 Basically, answer this question. But more detailly, this question is about tensor rather than numpy ndarray

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative to using [`torch.Tensor.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html) is to apply [`torch.Tensor.movedim`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.movedim.html#torch.movedim):

```
image.movedim(0,-1)
```

Which tends to be more general than `image.permute(1,2,0)`, since it works for any number of dimensions. It has the effect of moving `axis=0` to `axis=-1` in a sort of *insertion* operation.

The equivalent in Numpy is [`np.moveaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html).

Answer (score 13):

Find the method. use pytorch permute() method, see details: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pytorch-permute-method/

code:

```
image.permute(1, 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829711/what-is-the-correct-way-to-change-image-channel-ordering-between-channels-first)

```
img_plot = img.numpy().transpose(1, 2, 0)
plt.imshow(img_plot)
```